# Excel misconfigured and uses semicolon to recognize numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, input-languages

I managed to misconfigure something in Windows/Office/Excel... broken numbers are no longer identified by a comma or a point, but Excel uses semicolons now to recognize numbers.

[image]

I went through control panel -> language settings, but I can't find anything wrong there.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Any ideas how to fix something like that?

First check your Operating System language settings:

- Close Excel
- Start "Control Panel" > "Region and Language" (Windows 7, might be slightly different for other versions "Change date, time, or number formats")
- Click "Additional settings"
- Click "Numbers" tab
- Check the settings for "Decimal symbol" is `.`, "Digit grouping" is `,` and "List separator" is `,`
- Optionally, click "Reset" to restore all default settings
- Click "OK" and then click "OK again
- Restart Excel

If the above doesn't work then check the Excel "Use system separators" settings:

> - On the "File" tab click "Options"
>
>   [image]
> - Click "Advanced"
> - Enable "Use system separators"
>
>   [image]
> - Click "OK"

Source [Change the decimal point to a comma or vice versa](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2013/tips/change_the_decimal_point_to_a_comma_or_vice_versa.html)

Comment: Hi David, I just did that, for Dutch, English UK, English US. Even rebooted but it won't budge... the exact same problem. Any other ideas? Thanks (PS: I went for the reset button too, just to be sure)

Comment: @bas See updated answer ;)

Comment: ZOMG! that is just brilliant! thanks a lot, that did the trick. No idea how I managed to get this all messed up though, but it's fixed thanks to you!

Comment: Sometimes I think excel should not have any choice on those settings and not check the system either .... would reduce a whole bunch of errors, but I suppose one argument would be "I can't use an "xx" symbol because of religious preferences,or I'm right handed, I smoke,etc etc.... well explained anyway +1...